# Proof that $F(x)$ is an even function $f(x)$ is in $({-\infty},{+\infty})$ Continuous even function, and $F(x)=\int_0^x {(x-2t) \times f(t)dt}$.

Tags: functions

$f(x)$ is in $({-\infty},{+\infty})$  Continuous even function, and $F(x)=\int_0^x {(x-2t) \times f(t)dt}$. Proof that $F(x)$ is an even function.

Comment: This is a standard answer that F(x) is an even function. But it's very hard for me to proof it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(-x) = \int_{0}^{-x}(-x-2t)\ f(t)\ dt$$

$t=-s$ : $$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =-\int_{0}^{x}(-x+2s)\ f(-s)\ ds$$

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =\int_{0}^{x}(x-2s)\ f(s)\ ds$$

$$=F(x)$$

Therefore, $F$ is even.

Comment: +1 Simple, short, elegant...I liked it. Thanks

Comment: I am glad that you liked it! :)